# Prove $f(x) = 2x^2 - 3x + 1$ is continuous at $c = 2$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm taking an introductory analysis course and I can't seem to get this. Here is the definition for continuity at a point:

$f:A\rightarrow B$ is continuous at $c\in A$ iff:

$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|x - c|<\delta$ (and $x\in A)$ $\Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| <\epsilon$.

Here is my work thus far:

Note $f(c)=f(2)=3$.

I work backwards from $|f(x) - f(c)| <\epsilon$:

$|f(x) - f(c)| =  |2x^2 - 3x + 1 - 3| = |2x^2 -3x-2|=|(2x+1)(x-2)|$

I notice that $|x-2|$ is $|x-c|$ as $c=2$. Seems... convenient. Not sure where to go from here though, how can I get rid of that $(2x+1)$ term?

Comment: Polynomials are always continuous everywhere... the classical way this is proved is that the product of continuous functions are continuous and the sum of continuous functions are continuous and the identity function $id(x) = x$ is continuous.. which therefore implies that every polynomial is continuous. It seems silly to prove it for a specific polynomial at a specific point..

Comment: @MaithreyaSitaraman I agree, but more likely than not, given that this is an introductory analysis course the idea is to get used to the paradigm of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs.

Comment: @MichaelLee, fair fair... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\delta \leq 1$.  Then if $|x-2| < \delta$, then
$$
    -1 < x-2 < 1 \implies 1 < x < 3
$$
So 
$$
    3 < 2x+1 < 7
$$
which means that $|2x+1| < 7$.  Therefore,
$$
    |f(x) - f(2)| = |2x+1||x-2| < 7 \delta
$$
Suppose $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{7}$.  Then we have
$$
    |f(x) - f(2)| < 7 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{7} = \epsilon,
$$
and we're all set.

How can we ensure both $\delta \leq 1$ and $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{7}$?  By setting $\delta$ to be the minimum of these two.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in (1, 3)$, $\lvert 2x+1\rvert < 7$, so for $\epsilon > 0$, we let $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon/7)$. Then, $\lvert x-2\rvert < \delta$ implies $$\lvert 2x^2-3x-2\rvert = \lvert 2x+1\rvert\lvert x-2\rvert < 7\delta\leq \epsilon$$ Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} f(x) = f(2) = 0$, so $f$ is continuous at $x = 2$.